# How do I use svg in plotly.js instead of the accepted string markers?

Tags: javascript, svg, plotly-dash, plotly.js

In plotly.js you can specify DOM element, data, layout, etc...
So, in the data object, along other properties there is `marker: {symbol: []}` property available which let's one specify the desired shape marker. This property only accepts strings and numbers, [see here](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/scatter/#scatter-marker-symbol), representing a limited number of options. I want to use an svg icon instead of the accepted strings and numbers.

**Example from the docs:**

```
Plotly.newPlot(
    'myDiv', 
    data: {
        ...,
        marker: {
            symbol: // here only allowed to use number and string but I want to use svg
        },
        ...
    }, 
    layout
);
```

There is a property `shapes` inside layout that allows the use of svg and I read somewhere that I can somehow use that to populate trace marker.
This is where I read this: [link to comment suggesting the above idea](https://community.plotly.com/t/i-want-to-use-custom-icon-for-the-scatter-markers-how-to-do-it/6644/2).

How can I use svg icons instead of just string and numbers?